# Spring Integration Poller too slow

Tags: performance, spring, file, adapter, spring-integration

We have a Spring Integration project which uses a the following

```
 <int-file:inbound-channel-adapter
        directory="file:#{'${poller.landingzonepath}'.toLowerCase()}" channel="createMessageChannel"
        filename-regex="${ingestion.filenameRegex}" queue-size="10000"
        id="directoryPoller" scanner="leafScanner">
<!--        <int:poller fixed-rate="${ingestion.filepoller.interval:10000}" max-messages-per-poll="100" /> -->
        <int:poller fixed-rate="10000" max-messages-per-poll="1000" />
    </int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

We also have a leafScanner which extends from the default RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner, our leafscanner doesn't do too much. Just checks a directory against a regex property.

The issue we're seeing is one where there are 250,000 (.landed [the ones we care about] files) which means about 500k actual files in the directory that we are polling. This is redesign of an older system and the redesign was to make the application more scalable, whilst being agnostic of the directory names inside the polled parent directory. We wanted to get away from a poller per specific directory, but it seems unless we're doing something wrong, we'll have to go back to this.

If anyone has any possible solutions, or configuration items we could try please let me know. On my local machine with 66k .landed files, it takes about 16 minutes before the first file is presented to our transformer to do something.

Answer (score 2):

As the JavaDocs indicate, the `RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner` will not scale well with large directories or deep trees.

You could make your `leafScanner` stateful and, instead of subclassing `RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner`, subclass `DefaultDirectoryScanner` and implement `listEligibleFiles` and return when you have 1000 files after saving off where you are; and on the next poll, continue from where you left off; when you get to the end, start again at the beginning.

You could maintain state in a field (which would mean you'd start over after a JVM restart) or use some persistence.

Comment: Yes i read that about the RecursiveLeafOnlyDirectoryScanner but I couldn't find any upper limit mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update. The reason our implementation was so slow was beacuse of locking (trying to prevent duplicates), locking (preventing duplicates) is automatically disabled by adding a filter.
The max-messages-per-poll is also very important if you want to add a thread pool. Without this you will see no performance improvements.